# Datatables - Fixed column not working with ajax data

Tags: datatables

I am trying to use "Fixed columns" feature in datatables with remote data pulled using ajax. Everything works perfectly without any errors. However, the "Fixed columns" feature doesn't work. Below is my code

```
$('#dataTable').DataTable({
            "order": [[ groupColumn, "asc" ]],
            "rowReorder": true,
            "dom": 'l<"toolbar">frtip',
            "scrollX": true,
            "bscrollCollapse": true,
            "displayLength": 25,
            "fixedColumns": true,
            "columnDefs": [
                { "visible": false, "targets": groupColumn },
                { "orderable": true, "targets": groupColumn },
                { "orderable": false, "targets": "_all" }
            ],
            "processing": false,
            "pageLength": 60,
            "ajax": {
                url: "http://example.com/output",
                type: 'post',
                data: {id:id}
            },
    "columns": {
        //column definitions provided here
    }
 });
```

Comment: Where is `fixedColumns: true` in your example? Also, have you initialized the fixed columns [extension](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/)? Can you edit your question to clarify both of these?

Comment: it's included. however it works only with non ajax data

Comment: I am not able to recreate your problem. I have an Ajax-sourced data table, using the same configuration options as you are using (except for `columnDefs` and `columns`). The fixed columns feature is working correctly. Your problem probably comes from one of those two config items, or elsewhere. I am assuming that `groupColumn` is a JavaScript variable containing an integer.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle of your example?

Comment: Can you try removing options from your example, and see at what point it starts to work? Or, if you prefer, start with no options, except `fixedColumns`, and add options until it stops working? I could post a fiddle but it would not work with my ajax call - and so would not prove anything useful to you.

Comment: I tried by removing all the options you said and putting in hard coded values wherever possible, still I get the same result, it would be great if you post a fiddle, though with dummy data if you can.

Comment: OK, understood. Try starting with a working `fixedColumns` set-up, and add stuff until it breaks. And just to double-check again - have you initialized the fixed columns [extension](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/)?

Comment: See if this helps: [https://jsfiddle.net/rnk50esv/](https://jsfiddle.net/rnk50esv/). It uses ajax, but I included the related JSON as a comment, for reference. At least it may point you in the right direction - or clarify things, if I have missed the point of the problem!